# Get Colorbar Ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a colorbar in matplotlib and because I want my graph to be more sensitive I take the square root of each value. This gives me square rooted values on my colorbar, but now I want to scale the ticks labels back to the real values.  I am thusly having a hard time doing. I see that colorbar has a set_ticks function but I need to be able to get my ticks in the first place to do this generally.  Is there an easy way to do this that I am not seeing, or some other way around this?

Comment: [matplotlib documentation example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html)

Comment: I'm dubious about "because I want my graph to be more sensitive I take the square root of each value", though. By default the colorbar will run from the min to the max of the data in the plot. Also, a nonlinear relation of colors to the actual underlying difference might be misleading (do you have values both above and below 1?).

Comment: I should have said, instead of graph, that I am making a weighted 2D histogram with np.histogram2d.  Some values weren't quite as visible in my pcolormesh plot so I needed to sensitize it with something like log, but because I have values less than 1 I opted for sqrt.  This lead to my colorbar having sqrt ticks and I want to translate them back to the original values.  Through the example you linked I was able to get a hold of the ticks in a general way and change them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the locator for the colorbar instance should return the tick locations. 
`colorbar.locator()`.

Comment: Why is it not just called ``colorbar.get_ticks()``, like on an ``Axis`` object?!? This took me way too long to find.

Answer (score 1):

In matplotlib 2.1 you may use method `colorbar.get_ticks()`.